# Rails, fixtures and default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

I have a fixture for the model "SoftwareVersion":

```
testing:
  id: 4
  version: "4.0"
  file_name: MyString4
  is_testing: true
```

And a default scope for the model:

```
 default_scope where(is_testing: false)
```

If I do this in a test:

```
software_versions(:testing)
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find SoftwareVersion with id=4 [WHERE `software_versions`.`is_testing` = 0]
```

Is that intended behavior? And how do I override it?

Comment: Well in the fixture yo specify that is_testing is true and the default scope of the model is `is_testing: false` so how can the record be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is intended behavir, Default scope will affect all queries. Use unscoped to start a clean query again:

```
SoftwareVersion.unscoped.where(is_testing: true)
SoftwareVersion.unscoped.find(id: 4)
etc.
```

But that apart, if you're using the same table (with fixtures) for storing both Production and Testing records, then you're doing it wrong. Rails uses a totally different database for testing, so you don't need a column to distinguish. And if you put the fixtures under `test/fixtures`, they will never get loaded in production at all.

Comment: Oh - the is_testing field is used to determine if the SoftwareVersion is a test version only for test units (computers) or if they are ready for production use :-) The terminology is from an actual production app.

Comment: Aha - thanks for the clarification, but that was just a sidenote. Does `unscoped` answer your question though?

Comment: It does and it doesn't. I knew that I could use unscoped to get the record. What I wanted was to be able to use the shorthand software_versions(:testing). To keep the code clean and tidy. But I guess that this is the only way to do it so - yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is as intended, the only problem is that on your test database, there is no record of the SoftwareVersion. You only need to populate the database before running the tests. As you can see, the query is done perfectely, `WHERE software_versions.is_testing = 0`, with zero means `false` as in your `default_scope`.

Comment: I agree that is is obvious what's going on. But It is very difficult to use the fixture when it can't be referenced. One needs to be able to get the fixture unscoped...

Comment: Hmm, i see. The thing is the `.where` method queries the database in the instant that it is called. Maybe you should try a different approach, creating a new object using `.new` and passing the attributes as params, or whatever.